# Getting a Slice from OrderedDict (Key/Value) in Python

Tags: python

I have a collections.OrderedDict in Python.
And I need only the first 20 items from that list.

To get all the items:

```py
sortedResults = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(result.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True))

for key, value in sortedResults.items():
    print(f"User = {key} Voted {value} times")
```

But I only need the first 20.

### What I tried

- Slicing does not work on OrderdedDict
- Using ordereddict from ruamel.ordereddict (PyPi). This does not install (Python 3.10 with Spark here. Maybe that's with it does not work?)
- All the examples I see are not for Key/Value pairs

#### Back to old-school

This does work:

```py
sortedResults = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(result.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True))

i = 0
for key, value in sortedResults.items():
    i = i + 1
    if i == 20:
        break

    print(f"User = {key} Voted {value} times")
```

But that's very fortran/pascal (about 40 years back :-) )

There must be a better method in Python to get the first 20 items from an OrderedDict.
Is there?

Comment: Use [itertools.islice](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) - `itertools.islice(sortedResults.items(), 20)`

Comment: The `islice` solution is more efficient than the `list` solution below if the dictionary has a large number of elements.

Comment: Thanks everybody. itertools it is then. Tried it and works perfectly. Another step in understaning Python :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can convert the `items` to a list and slice that:

```
list(sortedResults.items())[:20]
```